# Enzyme Higher Order Component type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am attempting to test a HoC with Enzyme using the shallow renderer but I keep getting the following warning: `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Here is a simple example to reproduce the warning:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const testHoc = Wrapped => {
  return () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Wrapping</div>
        <Wrapped/>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

const Component = testHoc(<div>Hi</div>);
const wrapper = shallow(<Component/>);
```

I do not know why this is happening since I don't get any of these errors when the app is actually running, only when running tests. What is the cause of these warnings?

I am using React 16.3.2 and Enzyme 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  In the test you are passing a JSX Element to testHoc when you need to be passing a component.

```
// this is just a JSX Element
const element = (<div>Hi</div>);

// this is a simple React component
const SimpleComponent = () => (<div>Hi</div>);
```

Change the line where you are creating Component to be

```
const Component = testHoc(() => <div>Hi</div>);
```

and everything should work.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the explanation! Worked like a charm!